# Find a vector not in the image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x,y) = (5x+4y, -5x -4y) $ be a linear transformation. Find a vector w that is not in the image of T.

Ok so I have tried a few things:

Firstly I thought well if it is not in the image it is in the kernel. Worked out a basis for the kernel. Answer was wrong.

Then I saw online to find a basis for the image of T which I got to be $(5,-5)$ So any vector in the form a(5,-5) is in the image? But can't a be anything? So don't know how to find the answer.

Then I said Ok well the question is saying 
$5x+4y =a$
and 
$-5x-4y =b$
So pick an $a $and$ b $ so this is not satisfied. So I tried (1,1) and this is wrong also.

Please help me !!

Comment: If $(1,1)$ is wrong, then you can find $(x,y)$ such that $(5x+4y,-5x-4y)=(1,1)$. Do you see where this is going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:*

Notice that all vectors in the image are of the form $(z, -z)$. Given that, any vector not of that form cannot be in the image. For example ...

Comment: So for example (3,2) should work? But it is telling me I am wrong?

Comment: "It" being an autograding system? Then either it is not working correctly or the question you've written here isn't correct.

Comment: yes, it is webwork. The question is definitely written correctly, it must be something wrong with the way I am inputting it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(a,b)$ in the image of $T$, say $(a,b)=T(x,y)$ implies $a+b=(5x+4y)+(-5x-4y)=0$. Hence any $(a,b)$ with $a+b\ne 0$ is not in the image, for example $(a,b)=(\pi,1-\sqrt 2)$.